# apache server crash due to loading too many images on client side

Tags: php, image, apache, crash, photo

I'm working on a system at our company that displays employees photos in a tabular format. The photos are stored in the database and each photo can be viewed simply by calling the script: `employee_photo.php?id=[employee_id]`

Usually, when the client calls script `dept_employees.php` that shows employee details and photos, then while the server is sending the details to be rendered at client side browser, the Apache server crashes and error message appears

"Apache HTTP Server has stopped working"

I'm running XAMPP control panel v3.2.1

I feel it is something related to Apache configuration like: socket, buffer size,..etc. but I would appreciate someone to direct me for resolving this issue

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, and the problem was that I missed to include image type, when I'm returning image content in the script

`employee_photo.php?id=[employee_id]`

Thanks